# Clear Asp.Net TextBox Control on OnFocus with Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, web-controls

I have been scouring the interwebs and stackoverflow, but I have not come across a solution that works. I need to erase the default text from the textbox when onfocus happens. I know it is hitting onfocus because my class for text color is set in there also and the color is changing. Here's my code and what I have tried.

ASP:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddEditDel" runat="server" CssClass="txtAddEditDel" ></asp:TextBox>
```

The default text is some random instructions it populates on Page_Load.

Jquery:

```
$(".txtAddEditDel").focus(function () {
             var selectedRoleText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
             var selectedRoleId = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
             var selectedRoleIndex = $(this).find('option:selected').index();

            //enable add button
            enableDisableLinkButtons(true, true, true);

            if (selectedRoleText == 'Create, Edit, or Delete a Role Name.') {
                $(".txtAddEditDel:text").val('');
            }
            $(".txtAddEditDel").removeClass('placeholderText');

        });
```

The removeClass function is hit, but my value is not cleared. 
Heres what I have tried:

```
 $(".txtAddEditDel").val('');
 $(".txtAddEditDel").val("");
 $(".txtAddEditDel").text("");
 $(".txtAddEditDel").text == '';
 $(".txtAddEditDel").text == "";
 $(this).val('');
 document.getElementbyId('<%= txtAddEditDel.ClientID %'>.value = "";
```

Comment: Why not use placeholder attribute as a default text? It will be removed automatically. I.e. http://jsfiddle.net/qdthqkj1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(".txtAddEditDel").val(''); should work, assuming its getting there. Have you put some debugging information to check the if clause is true? It may be a better idea to check against the value of the option rather than the text, as the text could easily be misspelt or changed where as a default value will, in my experience, be '' or 0 in this scenario

Comment: That was it... i did debugger and some alerts and it just needed if ($(".txtAddEditDel").val() == 'Create, Edit, or Delete a Role Name.') {
                    $(".txtAddEditDel").val('');
                }